# Npm scripts - Critical css

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using Addy Osmani's 'Critical'
https://github.com/addyosmani/critical

the package.json below is working fine, but the build is only copying the critical css not extracting. I've tried --extract multiple places with and without a defined stylesheet, it seems i cant wrap my head around it.

```
{
 "name": "boilerplate",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "repository": "",
 "author": "",
 "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  "build:critical": "critical index.html --minify --css dist/css/style.css > dist/css/critical.css",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "critical": "^0.8.1",
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you output a HTML file instead, the CSS will be extracted. I had the same issue. Furthermore, in the output index file, the CSS link will have a rel="preload" automatically.

Here it's the command I am using:

```
critical dist/public/index.html --base dist/public --inline --minify > dist/public/index.critical.html
```

I hope that it will help.